# Accented letters in beamer with command \cite{}

Tags: beamer, accents

Why do accented letters become lower case when I use the \cite{} command in beamer? [image]

In te bib.tex I wrote it like this

```
@article{Randic,
author = {Randi\'{c}, M.},
  title = {On Characterization of Molecular Branching},
  journal = { Journal of the American Chemical Society},
  number = {97},
  year = {1975},
  pages = {609--6615},
  }
```

Comment: Please make a compilable minimal working example which allows us to reproduce the problem

Comment: bibtex needs `{\'c}` not `\'{c}`

Comment: David, it worked, that's right! Thank you!!